# How to clear the canvas without interrupting animations?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, canvas

I am visualising flight paths with D3 and Canvas. In short, I have data for each flight's origin and destination 
as well as the airport coordinates. The ideal end state is to have an indiviudal circle representing a plane moving
along each flight path from origin to destination. The current state is that each circle gets visualised along the path,
yet the removal of the previous circle along the line does not work as `clearRect` gets called nearly constantly.

Current state:

[image: canvas]

Ideal state (achieved with SVG):

[image: svg]

#### The Concept

Conceptually, an SVG path for each flight is produced in memory using D3's custom interpolation with `path.getTotalLength()` and `path.getPointAtLength()` to move the circle along the path.

The interpolator returns the points along the path at any given time of the transition. A simple drawing function takes these points and draws the circle.

#### Key functions

The visualisation gets kicked off with:

```
od_pairs.forEach(function(el, i) {
  fly(el[0], el[1]); // for example: fly('LHR', 'JFK')
});
```

The `fly()` function creates the SVG path in memory and a D3 selection of a circle (the 'plane') - also in memory.

```
function fly(origin, destination) {

  var pathElement = document.createElementNS(d3.namespaces.svg, 'path');

  var routeInMemory = d3.select(pathElement)
    .datum({
      type: 'LineString', 
      coordinates: [airportMap[origin], airportMap[destination]]
    })
    .attr('d', path);

  var plane = custom.append('plane');

  transition(plane, routeInMemory.node());

}
```

The plane gets transitioned along the path by the custom interpolater in the `delta()` function:

```
function transition(plane, route) {

  var l = route.getTotalLength();
  plane.transition()
      .duration(l * 50)
      .attrTween('pointCoordinates', delta(plane, route))
      // .on('end', function() { transition(plane, route); });

}

function delta(plane, path) {

  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  return function(i) {
    return function(t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      draw([p.x, p.y]);
    };
  };

}
```

... which calls the simple `draw()` function

```
function draw(coords) {

  // contextPlane.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);         << how to tame this?

  contextPlane.beginPath();
  contextPlane.arc(coords[0], coords[1], 1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  contextPlane.fillStyle = 'tomato';
  contextPlane.fill();

}
```

This results in an extending 'path' of circles as the circles get drawn yet not removed as shown in the first gif above.

Full code here: http://blockbuilder.org/larsvers/8e25c39921ca746df0c8995cce20d1a6

My question is, how can I achieve to draw only a single, current circle while the previous circle gets removed without interrupting other circles being drawn on the same canvas?

Some failed attempts:

- The natural answer is of course `context.clearRect()`, however, as there's a time delay (roughly a milisecond+) for each circle to be drawn as it needs to get through the function pipeline `clearRect` gets fired almost constantly.
- I tried to tame the perpetual clearing of the canvas by calling `clearRect` only at certain intervals (`Date.now() % 10 === 0` or the like) but that leads to no good either.
- Another thought was to calculate the previous circle's position and remove the area specifically with a small and specific `clearRect` definition within each `draw()` function.

Any pointers very much appreciated.

Comment: The standard way to handle this type of animation is to clear the whole canvas and redraw all for every frame. If this is to much of a load you can layer the canvas with the map and other details on one canvas and the other canvas for the flights and combine them for every frame.

Comment: A example for point along path (moving point) here https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868 I believe that only the initial points should be created and then moved across the route

Comment: @PiLHA That example is using SVG whereas the question explicitly asks for canvas...

Comment: Thanks @Blindman67. The flight paths are indeed on their own canvas layered on top of the map/airport layer. My problem is _when_ to clear the last frame and draw a new frame as the x and y positions of the ~150 flights come in at slightly different times.

Comment: @Ive I have added an answer that animates 800 points. The refresh rate will depend on the machine but most will do it in 60FPS. If you have different positions at different times the frame rate will make that inconsequential.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handling small dirty regions, especially if there is overlap between objects quickly becomes very computationally heavy.

As a general rule, a average Laptop/desktop can easily handle 800 animated objects if the computation to calculate position is simple.

This means that the simple way to animate is to clear the canvas and redraw every frame. Saves a lot of complex code that offers no advantage over the simple clear and redraw.

```js
const doFor = (count,callback) => {var i=0;while(i < count){callback(i++)}};
function createIcon(drawFunc){
    const icon = document.createElement("canvas");
    icon.width = icon.height = 10;
    drawFunc(icon.getContext("2d"));
    return icon;
}
function drawPlane(ctx){
    const cx = ctx.canvas.width / 2;
    const cy = ctx.canvas.height / 2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.lineWidth = cx / 2;
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(cx/2,cy)
    ctx.lineTo(cx * 1.5,cy);
    ctx.moveTo(cx,cy/2)
    ctx.lineTo(cx,cy*1.5)
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.lineWidth = cx / 4;
    ctx.moveTo(cx * 1.7,cy * 0.6)
    ctx.lineTo(cx * 1.7,cy*1.4)
    ctx.stroke();
    
}


const planes = {
    items : [],
    icon : createIcon(drawPlane),
    clear(){
        planes.items.length = 0;
    },
    add(x,y){
        planes.items.push({
            x,y,
            ax : 0,  // the direction of the x axis of this plane 
            ay : 0,
            dir : Math.random() * Math.PI * 2,
            speed : Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.1,
            dirV : (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.01, // change in direction
        })
    },
    update(){
        var i,p;
        for(i = 0; i < planes.items.length; i ++){
            p = planes.items[i];
            p.dir += p.dirV;
            p.ax = Math.cos(p.dir);
            p.ay = Math.sin(p.dir);
            p.x += p.ax * p.speed;
            p.y += p.ay * p.speed;
        }
    },
    draw(){
        var i,p;
        const w = canvas.width;
        const h = canvas.height;
        for(i = 0; i < planes.items.length; i ++){
            p = planes.items[i];
            var x = ((p.x % w) + w) % w; 
            var y = ((p.y % h) + h) % h; 
            ctx.setTransform(-p.ax,-p.ay,p.ay,-p.ax,x,y);
            ctx.drawImage(planes.icon,-planes.icon.width / 2,-planes.icon.height / 2);
        }
    }
}

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function mainLoop(){
    if(canvas.width !== innerWidth || canvas.height !== innerHeight){
        canvas.width = innerWidth;
        canvas.height = innerHeight;
        planes.clear();
        doFor(800,()=>{ planes.add(Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random() * canvas.height) })        
    }
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    // clear or render a background map
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    
    planes.update();
    planes.draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop)
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop)
```

```css
canvas {
   position : absolute;
   top : 0px;
   left : 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
800 animated points
```

As pointed out in the comments some machines may be able to draw a circle if one colour and all as one path slightly quicker (not all machines). The point of rendering an image is that it is invariant to the image complexity. Image rendering is dependent on the image size but colour and alpha setting per pixel have no effect on rendering speed. Thus I have changed the circle to show the direction of each point via a little plane icon.

#### Path follow example

I have added a way point object to each plane that in the demo has a random set of way points added. I called it path (could have used a better name) and a unique path is created for each plane.

The demo is to just show how you can incorporate the D3.js interpolation into the plane update function. The `plane.update` now calls the `path.getPos(time)` which returns true if the plane has arrived. If so the plane is remove. Else the new plane coordinates are used (stored in the path object for that plane) to set the position and direction.

Warning the code for path does little to no vetting and thus can easily be made to throw an error. It is assumed that you write the path interface to the D3.js functionality you want.

```js
const doFor = (count,callback) => {var i=0;while(i < count){callback(i++)}};
function createIcon(drawFunc){
    const icon = document.createElement("canvas");
    icon.width = icon.height = 10;
    drawFunc(icon.getContext("2d"));
    return icon;
}
function drawPlane(ctx){
    const cx = ctx.canvas.width / 2;
    const cy = ctx.canvas.height / 2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.lineWidth = cx / 2;
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(cx/2,cy)
    ctx.lineTo(cx * 1.5,cy);
    ctx.moveTo(cx,cy/2)
    ctx.lineTo(cx,cy*1.5)
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.lineWidth = cx / 4;
    ctx.moveTo(cx * 1.7,cy * 0.6)
    ctx.lineTo(cx * 1.7,cy*1.4)
    ctx.stroke();
    
}
const path = {
    wayPoints : null,  // holds way points
    nextTarget : null, // holds next target waypoint
    current : null, // hold previously passed way point
    x : 0, // current pos x
    y : 0, // current pos y
    addWayPoint(x,y,time){
        this.wayPoints.push({x,y,time});
    },
    start(){
        if(this.wayPoints.length > 1){
           this.current = this.wayPoints.shift();
           this.nextTarget = this.wayPoints.shift();
        }    
    },
    getNextTarget(){
        this.current = this.nextTarget;
        if(this.wayPoints.length === 0){ // no more way points
            return; 
        }
        this.nextTarget = this.wayPoints.shift(); // get the next target    
    },
    getPos(time){
        while(this.nextTarget.time < time && this.wayPoints.length > 0){
            this.getNextTarget(); // get targets untill the next target is ahead in time
        }
        if(this.nextTarget.time < time){
             return true; // has arrivecd at target
        }
        // get time normalised ove time between current and next
        var timeN = (time - this.current.time)  / (this.nextTarget.time - this.current.time);
        this.x = timeN * (this.nextTarget.x - this.current.x) + this.current.x;
        this.y = timeN * (this.nextTarget.y - this.current.y) + this.current.y;
        return false; // has not arrived
    }


}

const planes = {
    items : [],
    icon : createIcon(drawPlane),
    clear(){
        planes.items.length = 0;
    },
    add(x,y){
        var p;
        planes.items.push(p = {
            x,y,
            ax : 0,  // the direction of the x axis of this plane 
            ay : 0,
            path : Object.assign({},path,{wayPoints : []}),
        })
        return p; // return the plane
    },
    update(time){
        var i,p;
        for(i = 0; i < planes.items.length; i ++){
            p = planes.items[i];
            if(p.path.getPos(time)){ // target reached 
                planes.items.splice(i--,1); // remove            
            }else{
                p.dir = Math.atan2(p.y - p.path.y, p.x - p.path.x) + Math.PI; // add 180 because i drew plane wrong way around.
                p.ax = Math.cos(p.dir);
                p.ay = Math.sin(p.dir);
                p.x = p.path.x;
                p.y = p.path.y;
            }
        }
    },
    draw(){
        var i,p;
        const w = canvas.width;
        const h = canvas.height;
        for(i = 0; i < planes.items.length; i ++){
            p = planes.items[i];
            var x = ((p.x % w) + w) % w; 
            var y = ((p.y % h) + h) % h; 
            ctx.setTransform(-p.ax,-p.ay,p.ay,-p.ax,x,y);
            ctx.drawImage(planes.icon,-planes.icon.width / 2,-planes.icon.height / 2);
        }
    }
}

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function mainLoop(time){
    if(canvas.width !== innerWidth || canvas.height !== innerHeight){
        canvas.width = innerWidth;
        canvas.height = innerHeight;
        planes.clear();
        doFor(810,()=>{ 
            var p = planes.add(Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random() * canvas.height);
            // now add random number of way points
            var timeP = time;
            // info to create a random path
            var dir = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
            var x = p.x; 
            var y = p.y;
            doFor(Math.floor(Math.random() * 80 + 12),()=>{
                 var dist = Math.random() * 5 + 4;
                 x +=  Math.cos(dir) * dist;
                 y +=  Math.sin(dir) * dist;
                 dir += (Math.random()-0.5)*0.3;
                 timeP += Math.random() * 1000 + 500;
                 p.path.addWayPoint(x,y,timeP);            
            });
            // last waypoin at center of canvas.
            p.path.addWayPoint(canvas.width / 2,canvas.height / 2,timeP + 5000);            
            p.path.start();
        })        
    }
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    // clear or render a background map
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    
    planes.update(time);
    planes.draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop)
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop)
```

```css
canvas {
   position : absolute;
   top : 0px;
   left : 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
800 animated points
```

Comment: makes sense and as your code concisely shows I should probably 1) gather all updated points in an array (`planes.items`) 2) clear the frame 3) redraw. So far, my `draw()` function cleared the canvas and redrew each point individually.

Comment: @Ive Note that I have also created an icon to draw the plane pos rather than use ctx.arc and ctx.fill. Drawing an image can be slightly quicker than drawing via a vector call, for small numbers of renders there is no impact but for lots of repetitive rendering drawing an image will give 100 or more for the same cpu cost.

Comment: Note that if the entities are all the same color, then a single Path, composed of all the arcs might even be faster than drawImage (at least it is on my machine), and will allow for different radii  : https://jsfiddle.net/75mrhzdf/1

Comment: I like your update, but where `drawImage` wins is mostly with multi-colored shapes, even by keeping the plane drawing splitted like you did, path declaration is faster https://jsfiddle.net/75mrhzdf/4/ (and actually it seems to be on all devices I tested)

Comment: @Kaiido Its not the image rendering you are beating its the setTransform which uses more CPU time that the image render. Try the circles via image without the setTransform. Really I could create a bitmap with 10000 icons on it 10by10 with 100 by 100 on an image does that mean I can get 100000plus icons at 60fps. they have to be of practical use and you are rendering one shape not 800 individual shapes, add one more colour and you are forced to do a beginPath twice for each item which will crawl to a halt very quickly.

Comment: @Blindman67 in my fiddle I am calling `setTransform` twice per shape per frame, and it's still about 10 times faster than drawImage. Yes it's only one path (actually two with your plane shape) and that's why it wins. When possible (like in these cases)  composing one complex Path is faster than drawImage, that's my only point, and I make it clear that when dealing with multi-color shapes, it completely looses its advantages. Your bitmap example makes no sense, all shapes still have their own position and direction. you can't doit with an fixed bitmap...

Comment: @Kaiido The fiddle you linked is just managing 2 frames second, with images its up to around 10. guess my machine is too old. Maybe vector rendering is faster than bitmaps, (no just a passing thought)

Comment: @Kaiido Your running a Mac??

Comment: I do. And actually with the plane shape, Chrome does better with image... FF does better with path. With arc, both do better with path. And an other alternative is putImageData, as we already talked about together ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido This is not a browser issues but a hardware issues, you have a CPU oriented machine, I have a GPU centered machine, my machine does what it does best, draw images very fast, and your does general purpose computation very fast.  We can not use either as a guide to best performance. Side note FF on my machine is on average 2* faster than chrome at almost everything.

Comment: @Blindman67, @Kaiido that clearly clarifies the render. The problem I continue to have is in the scripting. The points in your examples are produced on demand by `add()`. The values in my example are produced via D3's own `attrTween()`, setting off a timer to produce the values along each path. In order to draw by frame I would need to 1) let D3 produce a single point per plane 2) pause the timer after I have 1 pt per plane 3) clear the frame and draw.  Unsure as to how to control especially step 2). A generator sounds reasonable, yet this project is ES5 bound. Are you aware of other ways?

Comment: @lve are the paths you interpolate with getPointAtLength linear or curved? Either way you just need to store the paths in an array for each object and interpolate. I will add another example showing what I mean as no room in comments.

Comment: @lve I have added an example path follow that is similar but not the same as your example. paths are coords plus times. Planes follow the paths until there are no more an then are removed. The demo is to show how `planes.update` was changed to follow the path, not how to implement the paths. You would change update to interface with D3 in a similar way

Comment: Many thanks for your help, time and code! I learned a lot and will add my implementation when done. Also, many thanks to @Kaiido.

Comment: Blindman67 @Kaiido here's the [final implementation](http://blockbuilder.org/larsvers/e8d808ea95405b8bd40b5df731af1491). Thanks again for your help and don't hold back in case you find any further optimisations...

Answer (score 3):

@Blindman67 is correct, **clear and redraw everything, every frame**.

I'm here just to say that when dealing with such primitive shapes as `arc` without too many color variations, it's actually better to use the `arc` method than `drawImage()`.

The idea is to wrap all your shapes in a single path declaration, using

```
ctx.beginPath(); // start path declaration
for(i; i<shapes.length; i++){ // loop through our points
  ctx.moveTo(pt.x + pt.radius, pt.y);  // default is lineTo and we don't want it
                                       // Note the '+ radius', arc starts at 3 o'clock
  ctx.arc(pt.x, pt.y, pt.radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
}
ctx.fill(); // a single fill()
```

This is faster than `drawImage`, but the main caveat is that it works only for single-colored set of shapes.

I've made an complex plotting app, where I do draw a lot (20K+) of entities, with animated positions. So what I do, is to store two sets of points, one un-sorted (actually sorted by radius), and one 
sorted by color. I then do use the *sorted-by-color* one in my animations loop, and when the animation is complete, I draw only the final frame with the *sorted-by-radius* (after I filtered the non visible entities). I achieve 60fps on most devices. When I tried with drawImage, I was stuck at about 10fps for 5K points.

Here is a modified version of Blindman67's good answer's snippet, using this single-path approach.

```js
/* All credits to SO user Blindman67 */
const doFor = (count,callback) => {var i=0;while(i < count){callback(i++)}};

const planes = {
    items : [],
    clear(){
        planes.items.length = 0;
    },
    add(x,y){
        planes.items.push({
            x,y,
            rad: 2,
            dir : Math.random() * Math.PI * 2,
            speed : Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.1,
            dirV : (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.01, // change in direction
        })
    },
    update(){
        var i,p;
        for(i = 0; i < planes.items.length; i ++){
            p = planes.items[i];
            p.dir += p.dirV;
            p.x += Math.cos(p.dir) * p.speed;
            p.y += Math.sin(p.dir) * p.speed;
        }
    },
    draw(){
        var i,p;
        const w = canvas.width;
        const h = canvas.height;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        for(i = 0; i < planes.items.length; i ++){
            p = planes.items[i];
            var x = ((p.x % w) + w) % w; 
            var y = ((p.y % h) + h) % h; 
            ctx.moveTo(x + p.rad, y)
            ctx.arc(x, y, p.rad, 0, Math.PI*2);
        }
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function mainLoop(){
    if(canvas.width !== innerWidth || canvas.height !== innerHeight){
        canvas.width = innerWidth;
        canvas.height = innerHeight;
        planes.clear();
        doFor(8000,()=>{ planes.add(Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random() * canvas.height) })        
    }
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    // clear or render a background map
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    
    planes.update();
    planes.draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop)
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop)
```

```css
canvas {
   position : absolute;
   top : 0px;
   left : 0px;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
8000 animated points
```

Not directly related but in case you've got part of your drawings that don't update at the same rate as the rest (e.g if you want to highlight an area of your map...) then you might also consider separating your drawings in different layers, on offscreen canvases. This way you'd have one canvas for the planes, that you'd clear every frame, and other canvas for other layers that you would update at different rate. But that's an other story.